# Content type HTML on PHP Page

Tags: php, html, xhtml

I found a Webpage saved as `something.php`. But the source code tells me `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

I also found out that PHP code does not work on the webpage.
What is the need for making the file extension PHP if HTML is used?
(Not exactly HTML, but XHTML)

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Comment: What's wrong with having HTML in a PHP file?  You can switch back and forth with `<?php` and `?>`.  What do you mean by "I also found out that PHP code does not work on the webpage"?  Does that mean your host doesn't support PHP?  That would seem unlikely  If there is PHP code inside the file you would have to hard code all HTML that was being generated by PHP before saving it as HTML.

Comment: There is no PHP currently. And any extra PHP does not work

Comment: I sounds like you're just starting out. Google "WAMP Server"

Comment: PHP only runs through a server, not when you load it from a local file.

Comment: By the way, the contents of the source code (like the doctype declaration and the `text/html` bits) do not determine the file type. The extension does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the need for making the file extension PHP if HTML is used?
>   (Not exactly HTML, but XHTML)

Considering your comments so far, particularly you stated there is no PHP; you can just change the file extension to XHTML.  You can always change it back.

I wonder what other PHP files exists where you "found" this page and why.  Assuming someone before you developed the site, there is probably a reason they used PHP file extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your host doesn't support PHP, then you should be able to run php code anywhere on that page by placing it inside "" tags. The 'Content-type' isn't relevant to whether PHP can run or not. Try adding the following code somewhere in your page:

```
<?php echo "Hey there, I'm a friendly PHP string!"; ?>
```

Comment: The problem is that PHP does not work at all. The tags do not execute.

Comment: Ah, then it sounds like wherever you are hosting this does not support PHP. If you know for sure the host supports PHP, the only thing I can think of is that your operating system is hiding file extensions, and the actual name of the file you found is something.php.html

Comment: So, if I load the page as `something.php.html` it ought to work?

Comment: No, that would be a situation where it would not work.

Comment: Where/how are you hosting this PHP file? On your local machine? On a webhost out on the net? If this is on your local machine, are you using something with PHP support to host it, such as XAMPP, WAMP, etc?

Answer (score 0):

add this `<?php echo "Hello!"; ?>` in your page to test, and make sure that your server is running, and normally it works

Comment: No offense intended, but is this different from my earlier suggestion?

Comment: yes exactly,i'm sorry i haven't refresh the page to see your answer before posting :)

Comment: this page in your localhost?

Comment: if your are in local machine, here's a few things you can check:
1-Make sure that your server is running correctly for example wampserver icon must be in green color
2-and your pages must be in www folder
3-Make sure you are accessing your file over your webserver using an URL like http://localhost/file.php not via local file access file://localhost/www/file.php

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a wamp/mamp server? Have you tried to turn it on?

These code are meta tags

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and it has nothing to do with php unless you have included a php script to it.

Html/XHtml will run even though you are not using a php server. All php files has a .php file extension and will run only if you use a server like wamp for windows or mamp for mac.

You can still use html/xhtml code in a .php file.

For example I have an `<h1>This is h1</h1>` tag and you want to make it dynamic, you can put `<?php ?>` inside the tag and echo it out to display, `<h1><?php echo "This is h1"; ?></h1>`.

In case you want to put html code inside a php script, you can do it like this

```
<?php echo "<h1>This is h1</h1>"; ?>
```

You can learn more about php and other programming languages by the help of google. Just take your time, relax and enjoy learning. Don't pressure yourself, remember learning is not a medicine that when you take it, it will work in a few minutes. Learning takes time and practice. Enjoy coding.